# How to get the observed value from more than one widgets ipywidgets

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, interactive, ipywidgets

I'm trying to create my own interactive path selector using interactive widgets from ipywidgets, there is supposed to be three select boxes, the second observes the value from the first one and the third observes the selected value from the previous both, and that's my problem, I can't figure out how to add the third widget.

Here is my functional code:

```
import os
import getpass
import glob
import ipywidgets as widgets
from ipywidgets import VBox, HBox, Label, interactive, Box

def return_paths(raw_path):
    """Create a list of folders in a given path
    skipping those with begin with '.' and are empty

    """
    paths = [folder for folder in os.listdir(raw_path) 
             if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(raw_path, folder)) and not folder.startswith('.') 
             and len(os.listdir(os.path.join(raw_path, folder))) != 0
    ]
    paths.sort()
    return paths

def get_select2(*args):
    options = return_paths(os.path.join(raw_path, select_1.value))  
    select_2.options = options

def process(Feature,ID):
    print(Feature,ID)

def run():
    w = interactive(process, Feature=select_1, ID=select_2)
    display(HBox([Label('Select the folder you want process:'), w.children[0], w.children[1]]))
    display(w.children[2])

user = getpass.getuser()
raw_path = f'/home/{user}/downloads/0_raw/'
raw_folders = []

select_1 = widgets.Select(
    options=return_paths(raw_path),
)

select_2 = widgets.Select()
select_3 = widgets.Select()
select_1.observe(get_select2)    

run()
```

In this moment is working with two selected boxes, how can I add the third one? any idea?

Comment: I understand why you want to do this from an academic point of view :) but if you want a simple widget filebrowser I think one exists already: https://pypi.org/project/ipyfilechooser/